# Question regarding "does"/"do"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, sentence, parts-of-speech, programming

What rule of grammar does this sentence break? (I mean the "does" part of the following sentence)

> What does the status indicators mean?

Also, why does english.stackexchange.com have a code option for formatting... Maybe BASIC or Apple script qualifies as English.

Comment: This almost seems like homework

Comment: @Simchona Well, there isn't any school right now, and I am definitely not in summer school. So, how could this be homework? +1 for great comment though. :)

Comment: I don't know whether or not you're in summer school, and the question you asked could be homework for someone learning English. I'm sorry if I caused offense.

Comment: Look - I'm a programmer, not an English teacher. Do most people remember specific rules like these? I forgive you, stranger.

Comment: I'm a programmer too. And usually I don't write a sentence and go "Dang! I messed up my subject-verb agreement!" It's a little more instinctual. Like knowing you need to have indentation in Python. (And if you're wondering about the code option, try putting it in Meta? It's a little off-topic here)

Comment: The second part of this question is answered on the meta site, here http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/529/is-the-code-sample-feature-really-needed-on-english-stackexchange/537#537

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Does* is singular.  *Indicators* is plural.  To use them together, as in your example, is to violate the **subject-verb agreement** of the sentence.

To create proper subject-verb agreement here would entail either changing the "does" to plural ("do"), or changing the "indicators" to singular ("indicator").

> What **do** the status indicators mean?
>
> What does the status **indicator** mean?

The first would probably be your choice, since I gather from the original example that there are in fact more than one indicator.

**However** (this is important), if the example question is asking what the phrase *the status indicators* means, the grammar is correct, but the phrase in question should be inside quotes or italicized:

> What does *the status indicators* mean?

Comment: It would be different if the question were "What does _status indicators_ mean?"

Comment: It's not so much that *does* is singular as it is that it's *third-person singular*.  You don't say *I does*, either.

Comment: Yes, but the answer is case-specific to save space.  In this example, the issue is _singular_ vs. _plural_, and _third-person singular_ vs. _plural_ is not pertinent.

Comment: @kiam: Good point.  That's important enough to include in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Subjects and verbs corresponds in person and number.

You don't normally write "I does", as *does* is used for the third singular person; *are* is not used for the first person singular, but for the plural person or the second person singular.
That is true also when using the negative form, and writing questions.

The sentence you wrote should be written "What do the status indicators mean?" or "What does the status indicator mean?"
The subject of your sentence is not *status* (which is singular), but *indicators* (which is plural); *status* is an attribute, a noun that is used to alter the noun that follows it, in the same way *expiration* in *expiration date* is used as attribute of *date*. *Status* could be the subject in "What is the current status?" and in that case you use *is* because the subject is the third person singular.

Your sentence could be correct if it were "What does 'status indicators' mean?" because there is an implicit word being used: "What does the 'status indicators' phrase mean?"

Comment: Nor is the subject "what", despite being in "subject position". Since this is a question, the question word goes first, regardless of its grammatical status.